# What happens if I get lots of downvotes for my answers?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

On Stack Overflow, I noticed that if I get 3 or more downvotes for my question, I am blocked from asking questions for 4 days.

Is that same applicable for answering questions?

If I get lots of downvotes for my answers, does that means I will get blocked from answering questions?

Comment: Yes, you will get blocked. (There's probably a duplicate question asking this, but I can't find it right now.)

Comment: Oh!!!@Glorfindel And I too cant find it so only asked the question.

Answer (score 8):

Question Bans and Answer Bans are independent, even if they share an [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th). In fact, one way to get out of a question ban is to post *quality* answers. (You can improve your questions to get them voted back up of course)

That said, it's worth trying to understand where you're going wrong with your posts rather than worry about whether you're getting question or answer banned.

I'd also advise you read the relevant help pages linked by the FAQ, since they talk about what sort of things to avoid. You've found meta - so it's worth taking the next step, and using the help provided to actually make your posts better.

Comment: Is ban applicable to voting too?

Comment: Not in that sense, no. But there's a different set of factors in play - you need a 15 reputation minimum to be able to vote after all

Comment: Thanks you  for your time @JourneymanGeek.

Comment: `the best/preferred way to get out of a question ban is to post quality answers` No, the *best* way to get out of a question ban is to improve your questions.  It is also by far the most effective way.  Feedback on answers *is* considered in a question ban (and vice versa) but only very slightly.

Comment: Oh, I think you're probably right there. Adjusted my answer to fit